# How did Andy make the tunnel with such a small hammer?

Tags: the-shawshank-redemption

How did Andy make such a large tunnel with such a little hammer?

Please help explain because I am confused. The tunnel is so big and the hammer is so small!

[image]

Answer (score 6):

It was not a one night job.
Andy escaped from Shawshank Prison. He had spent 19 years tunneling through the wall of his cell with his Rock Hammer.

> **How did Andy make such a large tunnel with such a little hammer?**

**Well the walls were soft and not reinforced or concertized and rock hammer worn out by the end.**

As Andy would say to Red **Geology is the study of pressure and time.** It took him 19 years to dig through.

[image]

Comment: It might be helpful if you corrected 'concertized' .... I would but I'm not sure what you were trying to say here.  The walls were some sort of concrete - just not very strong or reinforced with steel.

Answer (score 2):

Time.

As symbolized by the changing faces of the women on the poster covering the hole, from Rita Hayworth to Raquel Welch, Andy had many years in which to slowly carve his tunnel and carry out the debris.

Answer (score 2):

Andy used the hammer like a chisel, slowly carving his way through the wall over many years. in the scene that and is carving his name into the wall, we can see that the wall is quite soft, and easily carved.